# Find original index of reversed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reverse

I'm using the reverse() javascript function to reverse the objects held in a local storage array. But I'm trying to marry up the original index with the newly ordered array.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.indexOf("Apple"); //2
var fruitsReversed = fruits.reverse();
fruitsReversed.indexOf("Apple"); //1 -> I want to know that it used to be 2
```

Is there an easy way to do this? My actual case is a bit more complicated because the original string is in JSON format:

```
var data = {"info":[{"name":"Max"},{"name":"Alex},{"name":"Sam"},{"name":"Chris"}]}
```

...but I don't know if that would make a difference.

Update: I've got this working using using a bit of a work-around:

```
var fruitsLength = fruitsReversed.length-1; //3. subtract one because the first index is 0, not 1
var fruitIndex = fruitsLength - fruitsReversed.indexOf("Apple"); //2 (3-1)
```

So while this works, I think there must be a cleaner way...

Comment: I was going to suggest what you've done there, taking the length, and subtracting 1 to make it zero indexed and then subtracting the new position.  It doesn't seem so bad a solution, and if you find yourself doing this sort of thing in a few places, abstracting it out to a function would be just fine.

Comment: Can you add more information about why you need this index? If you are dealing with a list of objects, couldn't you store a reference to the object itself, not care about an array index?

Comment: Thanks for the support @Dymos

Comment: whats wrong in your code ?

Comment: @MattWay, I have an array of values stored in local storage (in a web app) which is added to over time. So, the most recent item is at the end of the array. I'm building a script to display the array elements in a jQuery Mobile listview, but I want the most recent at the top, rather than at the end, hence the use of `reverse()`. But then I want to be able to click on each list item to be able to edit it, and I want to be able to edit the local storage value rather than the temporarily reordered item. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Mahi, there's nothing 'wrong' - it works, I just think there must be a cleaner way to find actual indexes, rather than calculating them. The risk is that if the indexes somehow are non-contiguous or are reordered in some other way, then calculating them on the fly in this manner may produce an error.

Comment: @Brad `reverse()` happens in place. Are you able to post more code, showing how you utilise local storage in this case. I believe you can do this without worrying about indexes at all.

Comment: Happy to @MattWay. What do you mean it happens in place? How do think I can do it without worrying about indexes?

Comment: Because your array contains objects, and I am assuming you are only altering the object properties, not the objects themselves. This makes their index irrelevant when thinking about editing items. But it all depends how you are storing/loading to and from localStorage.

Comment: how do you access the objects while editing? with the index or with an id of the object?

Comment: Which part of this solution do you consider to be "unclean" ? I think it's perfectly clean.

Answer (score 2):

Return the index after substracting the length
return fruits.length -1-fruitsReversed.indexOf("Apple")

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly in your example `fruits === fruitsReversed`. I explain below about how `reverse()` happens in place.**

You mentioned in the comments that you need to display a reversed version of your array, except you want to edit the original. If your array contains sets of objects, then you don't need to worry about indexes at all. Consider this array:

```
var arr = [{ val: 1 }, { val: 2 }];
```

If you reverse this array, it will still contain the *original* objects, as only the reference is what changes. This means that if you only ever need to alter the array properties (eg. `val` in this case), just pass around references to the actual objects. For example:

```
var arr = [{ val: 1 }, { val: 2 }];
var anObject = arr[0];
arr.reverse();
// this changes the original objects value
anObject.val = 5;
// this prints 5
console.log(arr[1].val);
```

With this in mind, in your view, simply pass in the index of the item in the reversed array. Personally though, I would use a data binding library like angular or react, and just alter the items themselves, decoupling them from any array ordering.

---

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) also explain how `reverse()` changes in place.

> The reverse() method reverses an array in place. The first array element becomes the last, and the last array element becomes the first.

What this means is that the actual original array is altered, it isn't copied prior to reversing. You don't have to use what is returned, and can simply call `arr.reverse()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
myArray=[{"name":"Max"},{"name":"Alex"},{"name":"Sam"},{"name":"Chris"}];
pos = myArray.map(function(e) { return e.name; }).reverse().indexOf('Alex');
console.log("position before reverse="+pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an unique identifier in an object to access the object without need to know the index of the array.

Then you could reorder the array and the access via hash table is granted.

```js
var data = { info: [{ name: "Max" }, { name: "Alex" }, { name: "Sam" },{ name: "Chris" }] },
    hash = Object.create(null);

data.info.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.name] = a;
});

console.log(hash.Max);
console.log(hash["Sam"]);
console.log(hash);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```